# Schedule cron task to run at specific timezone

Tags: linux, cron

I placed the entry `CRON_TZ=Europe/Lisbon` as despicted on top of my crontab entry.

[image]

My system is configured in UTC and i would like to keep it that way since many of my application rely in UTC.

```
elgadmin@AZRSRVDM:~$ timedatectl
               Local time: Fri 2022-10-28 17:41:54 UTC
           Universal time: Fri 2022-10-28 17:41:54 UTC
                 RTC time: Fri 2022-10-28 17:41:54
                Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

I set the cron to run at 17:22:00 (at European/Lisbon time) but nothing happened.

From the manpage: https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab it states:

> The CRON_TZ specifies the time zone specific for the cron table. User
> type into the chosen table times in the time of the specified time
> zone. The time into log is taken from local time zone, where is the
> daemon running.

And it doesn´t speak further about it. I thought it would be straight forward.

What can i do to launch the cron tasks in the timezone referenced in the image, maintaining the UTC as the system time?

Thanks.

Comment: Did it run on a different time than exepcted, or it didn't run at all? was the txt file created?

Comment: For the time configured to run in the selected timezone it didn´t run, neither it appeared in the cron logs from my syslog any entry suggesting it did.
Once i take the CRON_TZ line it runs it UTC just fine.

Comment: @Revje the documentation is not obvious and further research i did about this issue seems a little bit confusing. I´m starting to think this "CRON_TZ" deal may not be for the instruction to launch at specific timezone but instead for the timezone set for the script to rely on.